# Can't export transmission map

Tags: modeling, export, glass

I'm trying to export a ring that has some transparent parts, but when i open the file that i exported, my transmission map is not there anymore, so the ruby becomes opaque. (No matter the format .fbx , .gltf ...)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You plugged your *Transmission map* into Alpha input.
Alpha input considers white color as *opaque*.

[image]

Comment: Thats's the problem, it's not me that plugged it, but it is automatic when i export it, that's what i don't understand. Why every map is supported excepted the transmission map ?

Comment: Hey :). Exporting materials is tricky, and often not fully supported. Even the newest gITF doesn't support everything. Related answer: [No materials on .fbx import](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57541/78972)

Comment: I already read this that's why i tried to bake maps, and use .GLTF but it solves nothing. There surely should be a solution, how is there so many glass objects on CGtrader made with blender ?

Comment: Exporting transmission textures to glTF is supported by recent versions of Blender (see https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/pull/1094), but note that it's a newer feature in glTF and not all viewers support it yet. A good glTF viewer to test such files is https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/.